# fetching same error messages 2 times of paperclip in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Hi I have given my attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :attach,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
                    :path => "/contents/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach,
                                    :content_type => ['application/msword',
                                                       'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                                                       'application/pdf'],
                                    :if => Proc.new { |f| f.attachable_type == 'Interview' }
  validates_attachment_content_type :attach,
                                    :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'],
                                    :if => Proc.new { |f| f.attachable_type == 'Designation' || 'Department' },
                                    :message => I18n.t('content_type', :scope => 'paperclip.errors.attachment')

end
```

in my controller action have defined this:

```
 def create
    @designation = Designation.create(designation_params)
   if @designation.errors.present?
     p @designation.errors
      render :action => :new
    else
      redirect_to designations_path, notice: I18n.t('designation_created')
    end
  end
```

code in designation model:

```
has_one :attachment, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachment
```

in en.yml

```
en.
 paperclip:
    errors:
      attachment:
        content_type: The image format you are trying to upload is not supported. Please upload an image of format JPG, GIF or PNG
        presence: Cant' be blank
```

So whenever error it shows two times I got this in my console

> ## ,
>
> @messages={:"attachment.attach_content_type"=>["The image format you
>   are trying to upload is not supported. Please upload an image of
>   format JPG, GIF or PNG"], :"attachment.attach"=>["The image format you
>   are trying to upload is not supported. Please upload an image of
>   format JPG, GIF or PNG"]}>

Please guide me how to overcome with this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code means if attachable type is 'Designation' or if 'Department' string is evaluated to `true` (I guarantee it does).

```
Proc.new { |f| f.attachable_type == 'Designation' || 'Department' }
```

Probably you tried to wrote something like

```
Proc.new { |f| f.attachable_type == 'Designation' || f.attachable_type ='Department' }
```